# Cannot predict image dataset

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to predict an image dataset with an already trained network.But strangly I get this error message:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected title to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 64, 3)
```

However my dataset should have 5000 pictures inside.I got confused...
Here is my code:

```
def preprocess_image(path):
image=tf.io.read_file(path)
image=tf.image.decode_jpeg(image,channels=3)
image=tf.image.resize(image,[64,64])
image/=255.0
return image

def gen_image_dataset(path):
img_path=[]
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        img_path.append(name)
path_ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_path)
image_ds=path_ds.map(preprocess_image,num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
return image_ds

PlateData(5000,273,76,1)
test_dataset=gen_image_dataset("/home/ly0kos/Car/temp/")
result=model.predict(test_dataset)
```

Thank you so much for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming because input expects `(None, 64, 64, 3)` but you are passing `(64, 64, 3)`. Just add `batch()` in the end.

```
return image_ds.batch(<batch_size>,False)
```